# Seeing place names in Google Earth Pro?

Tags: google-earth-pro

I have just downloaded and installed Google Earth Pro, and I cannot get place names to show up at all.

Can you suggest a course of action?

Comment: Can you confirm that in the Layers panel (bottom left), the boxes next to "Borders and Labels" and "Places" are both checked on? Then, do place icons show up when you zoom in to the town/block level? Many place markers will only show the label on the map when you hover over them with your mouse cursor.

Comment: Hi Christiaan. Thank you for getting back to me so quickly. Yes, both of those are on, but nothing is showing up. This problem has only arisen since I installed the new 'Pro' version. I am not sure how it is better than the previous version, and I may prefer to go back to that, if it is possible and this problem cannot be fixed.

Comment: Lewis, can you see the built-in data on the map, like country borders, city names, etc? Or is all that blank? Alternatively, is the issue that you're no longer seeing makers for places that you put on the map yourself, either via KML files that you loaded or things you drew yourself? There have been some recent issues with the data in "My Places" disappearing during the upgrade... if that's what happened, then I can hopefully help you get that data back.

Comment: Hi Christiaan. This is very weird. I left Google Earth open for an hour while I did something else, and gradually all the information turned up. So, I tried it again this morning and it did the same thing. It's just incredibly slow to turn up. I don't know what could cause that.

Comment: Strange indeed.  Glad the data is showing, but being super slow to load is unusual.  Maybe try clearing your memory and disk caches in Google Earth? Those are under Tools > Options (Windows) or Google Earth > Preferences (Mac), then the Cache tab.

Comment: https://www.screencast.com/t/z6Ex9vvmc

Comment: Thanks for the video. Strange indeed.

Can you test again with everything in the "Places" panel turned OFF, including the fire mapping KML? The stuff in Places comes from KMLs that you've loaded locally, and some, like the fire file, are dynamically loading content via "network links"... so there are a whole set of additional considerations with that kind of content. Let's first confirm whether there's an issue with the built-in (Google-provided) data in the "Layers" panel. 
Also... did you clear your caches? And can you check what version of Earth you are running (Help menu > About)?

Comment: I did what you suggested and cleared all caches, but it still remains very slow.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem....finally fixed it.  Right click on name of tour.  Under properties, uncheck box near the top labeled, "Show contents as options (radio button selection).  Click "OK".  Now the box to the left of the tour destinations may be checked (or unchecked) that will show or hide the names of ALL the tour points.